# Proper name for divs/spans/p/img/a/tr/td/ul/li et al

Tags: javascript, html

Just curious, I find whenever I have a page element '<###>[content]<###>' and I want to know how to do something with it, I usually google something along the lines of "how to do x with div" or "how to get y from div". I know that div's are specific page elements, so 'div' is probably not the proper name, but I find in practice, it's what several other people use as well.

What, if any, is the proper name for a generic element created by '<###>[content]<###>'?

Comment: erm... "element"? or maybe "tag"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call it tag or HTMLElement :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement

Comment: Calling it a tag isn't correct. `<a>` is a tag, which is used to create an element (or a DOM node).